mplfinance error，Data for column "Open" must be ALL float or int
the code works three days ago
#!pip install mplfinance
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import mplfinance as mpf

# get data
symbol = "AAPL"
start_date = "2022-01-01"
end_date = "2022-12-31"
stock_data = yf.download(symbol, start=start_date, end=end_date)

# index
stock_data.index = pd.to_datetime(stock_data.index)

# K_line
mpf.plot(stock_data, type='candle', style='yahoo', title=f'{symbol} ')

I convert the type to float or int, but it still don't work,
pic

It's unclear what information is present inside the stockdata variable, which seems to be the cause of your error. Perhaps these are numeric values casted to a string causing the given error or something along those lines. Can you provide the data inside the stock_data variable?

The error is due to the column names being multi-column, which can be addressed by changing them to single columns. stock_data.columns = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']

There is a multi_level_index in the download parameters which you can set to false.
stock_data = yf.download(symbol, start=start_date, end=end_date, multi_level_index=False)

I had the same problem
Code:
stock_data = yf.download(symbol, start=start_date, end=end_date)

Change to:
aapl = yf.Ticker(symbol)
stock_data = aapl.history(start=start_date, end=end_date)

I don't know why but it works for me.

this works for me too thanks for saving my time
